# how do i determine which questions to ask a user in a quiz based on previous answers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of questions in a category, and want to choose a subset of them to ask the user based on which ones they answered right/wrong previously.
I want to make it random, but in a way that the ones they have more trouble with are asked more frequently.

**EDIT**: I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the weight/bias/score for each question based on the number of times they've answered it right/wrong.

I came up with the following, but it seems odd to me:
I assign a score to each question based on how many times they answered it right/wrong
Obviously, if they've never been asked that question I need to assign an arbitrary score (I chose 5)
For all other question, I use the formula

```
score = wrong*2-right
```

so if I had the following 10 questions, the "score" would be calculated for each of them (R=# of times they got it right, W=# of times they got it wrong and S=score). From there, I take the lowest score and assign that a probability of 1 (in this case it was id=5 with a score of -7). I then take the difference between the lowest score and the second lowest score (id=1 with -5, a difference of 2) and assign it a probability of 1 + the difference = 3.
I continue this for every question, and then at the end I can just choose a random number between Min(1) and Max(82) and select the question that has the highest P where random < P. So if my random # was 79 I would choose id=2.

But this seems long and convoluted. Is there an easier way to do this (I'm using PHP and mysql, But I plan to do this within an app with a local datastore as well)

```
id  R   W   S   P   
1   5   0   -5  3   
2   3   5   7   82  
3   6   2   -2  8   
4   2   2   2   23      
5   9   1   -7  1   
6   3   1   -1  14  
7   0   0   5   68
8   7   5   3   33
9   6   5   4   44
10  3   4   5   56
```

**EDIT:** to clarify, I'm stuck on the issue of "weight" (P value in my example)...I'm trying to find a good (and fast) way of calculating the "weight" for each problem, given the number of right and wrong answers they've given for the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your answer correctly but it seems you are looking for a sort of "weighted" random number generator. In essense what you want to do is give the problems they are having issues with more weight. Perhaps create a class called questions with a property of weight in it. That property can hold how much weight you put in it. Then when you select a random number generator use something like this.

http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/

Comment: to clarify, I'm stuck on the issue of "weight"...I'm trying to find a good way of calculating the "weight" for each problem, given the number of right and wrong answers they've given for the question

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I realize that my initial method of calculating a weight is bit slow. After using the formula, I end up with some -ve weights. I then have to go through each one and add ABS(MIN(S)) to each weight, which is unnecessary.

My new formula would be S = CEILING(Wrong * 5 / Right)

Obviously I'd need to account for 0 values, so the code would be:

```
if (R == 0 AND W == 0) S = 10
else if (R == 0)       S = W*5
else if (W == 0)       S = CEILING(5/R)
else                   S = CEILING(W * 5 / R)
```

I've worked out the numbers for a few sample sets and this gives me fairly good results. It also allows me to keep the SCORE value updated in the database, so it doesn't need to be recalculated every time (just updated whenever that question is answered)
Once I have a set of 60 or so questions and I want to choose 5 or 10 of them, I can just create a random # between 1-SUM(SCORE) and then use a binary search to figure out which question that represents.

If anyone has a better suggestion for calculating the score/weight/bias or whatever it's called, I'd appreciate it.